# Meeting multiple conditions that aren’t set simultaneously in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to use `componentWillReceiveProps()` to call a method in my component once three conditions are met. Two of these conditions compare current props to next props, and those two receive their values via an Ajax request. The problem is not all conditions will be true *at the same time*.

For example.

```
export class Styles extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (
            !_.isEmpty(nextProps.one) &&                    // set via ajax request
            !isEqual(this.props.two, nextProps.two) &&
            !isEqual(this.props.three, nextProps.three)     // set via ajax request
        ) {
            this.myMethod();
        }
    }

    myMethod() {
        … do something
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div />
        )
    }
}
```

Because two of the props are being set with an Ajax response, I can’t be sure when those values are set and when they’ll fulfill the condition. I obviously need to achieve three `true` values in order to call `this.myMethod()`, but instead I get various combinations of `true/false` at any given time. It’s a bit of a lottery scenario.

Do I ultimately need to manage each of these conditions temporarily in state, then clear them out when they’re met?

Comment: Will `nextProps.one` etc. be `undefined` until they are set? Could you then not just use `if (nextProps.one && nextProps.two && nextProps.three) { this.myMethod(); }`?

Comment: Hi @Tholle — Not bad idea, but I do need to be able to compare current and next values for props `two` and `three`. `nextProps.one` is null initially, yeah.

Comment: Alright. Then it would probably be best to keep three values on the instance like you said. `if (!this.conditionTwoMet) { this.conditionTwoMet = !isEqual(this.props.two, nextProps.two); } ... if (this.conditionOneMet && this.conditionTwoMet && this.conditionThreeMet) { this.myMethod(); }` Since you won't use it for rendering, you don't need to put it in state.

Comment: It would probably be easier to not render the component until your props are loaded, though.

Comment: The component is already loaded with older data. The above happens when clicking a button that refreshes a few props.

Comment: One method I can think of that can solve this is to combine your two `ajax` requests in a `Promise.all`. Pretty much, your app will wait for both `ajax` requests to finish and then you can update your component. This allows you to view `prevProps` the way you want to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this without the deprecated `componentWillReceiveProps` with something like this:

```
export class Styles extends Component {
  isDirtyTwo = false;
  isDirtyThree = false;
  ..
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this.isDirtyTwo = this.isDirtyTwo || !isEqual(prevProps.two, this.props.two);
    this.isDirtyThree = this.isDirtyThree || !isEqual(prevProps.three, this.props.three);
    if (!_.isEmpty(this.props.one) && this.isDirtyTwo && this.isDirtyThree) {
      this.isDirtyTwo = false;
      this.isDirtyThree = false;
      this.myMethod();
    }
  }
  ..
}
```

This will call `myMethod` when `one` is empty and both other props have changed at some point. (I'm assuming that once `one` is empty it stays that way, but if not, you could add another property for it.)

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. :)

Comment: :-) I already noticed the question was a couple of hours old. Anyway, I think it's the most straightforward method, even though @Brett's promise idea also sounds feasible.